# Expressjs variable value is not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, variables, mean-stack

In below code snippet, I declare one variable named `sumOfRevenue`. I set its value as 10 in router and then try to print its value but I am getting it blank. So may I know why I got blank rather then 10?

Please check below code and attached screenshot.

```js
const express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
const client = require('../models/db')

/* I defined sumOfRevenue variable as below */
sumOfRevenue = ""  

router.get('/getSites', async(req, res) => {
  await client.query('select sum(revenue) from deals ', (error, results) => {
    if (!error) 
      /* Here I just store static value as 10 to this variable */
      sumOfRevenue =10
    })
    /* Here when I want to get that value but it gives blank */
    console.log("sumOfRevenue is:" + sumOfRevenue);
});

module.exports = router
```

[image]

Comment: you're using await with callback... It's suspicious. (not necessarily wrong)

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add `var` or `let` to declare your variable.
- You need to be sure "!error" is equal to "true" (`console.log(!error)`)

Comment: I tried to set let or var both way to declare variables and also set !error to true but still not getting updated value of variable.